# How to store "semi-constant", associated data in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

So,let's say I need a list of `categories` and `sub_categories` to be associated with the table `products`. Of course, `categories` has_many `sub_categories`.

`categories` and `sub_categories` should rarely change, but it's still possible to do with an admin account (from CMS) so I can't hardcode these values.

Here's an example:

```
// Last week
categories: [A, B, C]
sub_categories: [1, 2, 3]

// Today
categories: [A, B, D]
sub_categories: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Let's say that Today's category and sub category changes are made in the production server. **How do I easily update these values in my staging server**?

I've explored the `seed.rb` option, but it's confusing to deal with modifications, and having to manually edit the `seed.rb` everytime there's change in production server (I think), unless there's another way to do this. Also there's the association problem between `categories` and `sub_categories`.

Note that `categories` table is a lot like `countries`, `area_codes`, or `marital_statuses`. Except that changes are more frequent.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks!

**Update**: here's the generated file from `SeedFu::Writer`:

```
Category.seed(:id,
   #<Category id: 1, name: A>
   #<Category id: 2, name: B>
)
```

The seeds are commented out. Is this normal?

Comment: It's looks like separate issue from your question. Please move it to separate question with code that utilises writer. Because it incorrect with lines commented out but this code is related to solution not problem you try to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that [seed-fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) may help you. You can create a model for this template data and then write a rake task for write and update a seed-fu file from this model.

[Here is documentation](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu/blob/master/lib/seed-fu/writer.rb) for writer module.

After update of seed-fu file you can commit it to git from same task and then you [just include it](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu/blob/master/README.md#capistrano-deployment) into your Capistrano deploy.

Comment: So, I need to create a custom rake task that generates a seedfu file from existing tables. How do I import that file when I want to use them in another environment? Thanks.

Comment: There is same git repository when you deploy. So you just put this file in git and commit it on finish of this task.

Comment: Last question: will this break any relations between `Category` and `SubCategory`? (resetted IDs, etc.)

Comment: Seed-fu solves this problem with id by [including ids in seed](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu#terser-syntax). It's main reason to offer you this solution. So you just create seeds in hierarchy order and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. Why are the lines commented out by the way? `Category.seed(:id, #<Category id: 1 ....`

Comment: Update your question with "update:" section for this. It's unreadable here.